# Issues with running Fiddlercore as a windows service

Tags: c#, service, fiddler, fiddlercore

When running Fiddlercore as a windows service (using the C# service template), it appears to quit after downloading the first 50-100bytes of a web page. This is often enough to get the title of the page and some of the header HTML, but no more.

I have 'hacked' in the ability for the service to run in console mode (not as a service), and while in this mode Fiddler works perfectly!

Assuming that this was maybe something to do with permissions, I changed the windows service to run under my account instead of 'Local System', however this did not work.

What could possibly be the cause? I have no idea how to try and debug this issue!

Update: here is the basic code:

Program.cs

```
namespace router
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new router() 
            };
            if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            }
            else
            {
                RunInteractive(ServicesToRun);
            }
        }

        static void RunInteractive(ServiceBase[] servicesToRun)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Services running in interactive mode.");
            Console.WriteLine();

            MethodInfo onStartMethod = typeof(ServiceBase).GetMethod("OnStart",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            foreach (ServiceBase service in servicesToRun)
            {
                Console.Write("Starting {0}...", service.ServiceName);
                Console.WriteLine();
                onStartMethod.Invoke(service, new object[] { new string[] { } });
                Console.Write("Started");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(
                "Press any key to stop the services and end the process...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine();

            MethodInfo onStopMethod = typeof(ServiceBase).GetMethod("OnStop",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            foreach (ServiceBase service in servicesToRun)
            {
                Console.Write("Stopping {0}...", service.ServiceName);
                onStopMethod.Invoke(service, null);
                Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("All services stopped.");
            // Keep the console alive for a second to allow the user to see the message.
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Service1.cs

```
namespace router
{
    public partial class router : ServiceBase
    {
        public router()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            ProxyUtils.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            ProxyUtils.stopProxy();
        }
    }
}
```

ProxyExtension.cs

```
namespace ProxyExtension
{
    public static class ProxyUtils
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
                startProxy();
        }

        public static void startProxy()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Fiddler.Session> oAllSessions = new List<Fiddler.Session>();
                // Allow certificate errors from websites
                Fiddler.CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = true;

                // Create root certificate
                CertMaker.createRootCert();
                setMachineTrust(CertMaker.GetRootCertificate());

                // Switch off system proxy
                FiddlerCoreStartupFlags oFCSF = FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default;
                oFCSF = (oFCSF & ~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy);

                // start proxy
                Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8080,oFCSF);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error starting proxy: " + e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hard to say unless you post a [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) so that we can reproduce the problem

Comment: James No, you posted all unrelated parts. Have you read the link I posted? How do you use `oAllSessions`? Do you syncronize access to it? Where is your session handler? The key point is: Assume you are trying to answer this question, which info would you need?

Comment: Sorry, the only missing part of code is the #region AttachEventListeners which is a direct copy from this example: http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore-demo2

Comment: Do you think what you do in that function is not relevant. OK good luck...

Comment: No, but my assumption was that as that section of code was direct from the Fiddler examples and it appeared to be working fine, then the code that I had inserted to have it run as a service was the more likely culprit.

Comment: What exactly does "It appears to quit" mean? Where are you looking at the content? Are you trapping exceptions? What traffic are you trying to capture (since you've said it shouldn't register as the proxy)?